# Python removing first 3 digits in a number

Tags: python

Hopefully a simple one, I have a number, say `1234567.890` this number could be anything but will be this length.

How do I truncate the first 3 numbers so it turns into `4567.890`?

This could be any number so subtracting 123000 will not work.

---

I'm working with map data in UTM coordinates (but that should not matter)

### Example

```
x = 580992.528
y = 4275267.719
```

For x, I want `992.528`

For y, I want `267.719`

**Note:** y has an extra digit to the left of the decimal so 4 need removing

Comment: Do you need the trailing `0` at the end?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the first 3 digits? I get the impression that you may have limited the scope of your question to the task you are currently working on when there might in fact be a better solution with a slightly different approach to the larger problem.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan it's a placeholder

Comment: I'm working with coordinate data and the visualiser cannot handle UTM coordinates as they are too long, so I want to trim them from the front, view them, then add them back. Ah which means I need to record what gets trimmed...

Comment: @SpatialDigger you might find it helpful to try using https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html. `Decimal` is oriented towards storing values which are far too large/long or require a high level of precision to store normally. Python would probably work fine if you substituted `Decimal` instances for the numbers, but it might give your visualizer some issues. You can apply an offset to all of your points and convert them back to regular numbers with `float(x)` for display. The important part is that it would ensure the splitting does not mess with the formatting/accuracy of the numbers.

Comment: This would be so much easier if it were about keeping everything up the the "thousands-digit" or if the number of digits before and after the dot were fixed. "First three digits" seems tricky, except for the obvious way via string.

Comment: Post us a couple of  examples of UTM coordinates, is it given they have six digits e.g. 18N 780950E 2052283N?

Comment: Why should `1234567.890` become `4567.890` but `4275267.719` should become `267.719`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for this:

```py
x = 1234567.890

# This is still a float
x = float(str(x)[3:])

print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
4567.89
```

---

As `[3:]` gets the starts the index at `3` and continues to the end of the string

Comment: Any way to do this without converting to a string?

Comment: Not sure there sorry, best I can do is cast it back to a float after

Comment: I guess roundup to the nearest 10,000, then subtract this value?

Answer (score 2):

**Update after your edit**

The simplest way is to use `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def fmod(v, m=1000, /):
    return float(Decimal(str(v)) % m)

print(fmod(x))
print(fmod(y))
```

Output

```
992.528
267.719
```

---

If you don't use string, you will have some problems with floating point in Python.

Demo:

```
n = 1234567.890
i = 0
while True:
    m = int(n // 10**i)
    if m < 1000:
        break
    i += 1
r = n % 10**i
```

Output:

```
>>> r
4567.889999999898

>>> round(r, 3)
4567.89
```

Same with `Decimal` from [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module:

```
from decimal import Decimal

n = 1234567.890
n = Decimal(str(n))
i = 0
while True:
    m = int(n // 10**i)
    if m < 1000:
        break
    i += 1
r = n % 10**i
```

Output:

```
>>> r
Decimal('4567.89')

>>> float(r)
4567.89
```

Comment: Slight variation: `r = n % 10**i`

Comment: With `decimal`, I think you can use the `logb` method instead of your loop (not sure it's the best, didn't read it all). Then again, in that solution you're using string, in which case Freddy's continuation seems much simpler anyway :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy. I used string just to show it's mandatory for this kind of problem due to the representation of floating point in python. My first solution doesn't use string and works except for the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

This approach simply implements your idea.

> - `int_len` is the length of the integer part that we keep
> - `sub` is the rounded value that we will subtract the original float by

### Code

Here is the code that implements your idea.

```py
import math


def trim(n, digits):
    int_len = len(str(int(n))) - digits  # length of 4567
    sub = math.floor(n / 10 **int_len) * 10**int_len

    print(n - sub)
```

But as Kelly Bundy has pointed out, you can use modulo operation to avoid the complicated process of finding the subtrahend.

```py
def trim(n, digits):
    int_len = len(str(int(n))) - digits  # length of 4567

    print(n % 10**int_len)
```

### Output

The floating point thing is a bit cursed and you may want to take [Corralien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71446705/16936415) as an alternative.

```py
>>> n = 1234567.890

>>> trim(n, 3)
4567.889999999898
```

Comment: What's the advantage over `return n % 10**int_len`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Woah wait a minute, that worked too. Thank you, by the way.

Comment: Just like in Corralien's answer :-P

Answer (score -2):

```
def get_slice(number, split_n):
  return number - (number // 10**split_n) * 10**split_n
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].